# Handle triple condition with *ngIf else

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I would like to suggest establishments to the user based on its location.

I must handle to cases:

1. The user granted the geolocation service
2. The user did not granted the geolocation service

I want to display a loading message while I am both checking if the geolocation service is granted and (if yes) while looking out for the establishments.

I tried something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="(suggestedPlaces$ | async) || clocationAvailable !== undefined; else loading" >
      <div *ngFor="let place of suggestedPlaces$ | async">
        <ion-card (click)="onSuggestedPlaceSelected(place)">
          <!--<ion-img width="2OO" height="200" src="{{place.photo}}">
        </ion-img>-->
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
              {{place.name}} - {{place.rating}}
            </ion-card-title>
            <p>
              {{place.vicinity}}
            </p>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div #loading padding text-center>
        <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
        <p>
          Chargement...
        </p>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="clocationAvailable === false" class="message-box message-box-alert">
      <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-1>
            <ion-icon name="alert"></ion-icon>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            Could not geolocate you
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </div>
```

In my controller I wrote the following:

```
clocationAvailable: boolean;

ionViewDidLoad() {
    // Start to geolocate the user in order to suggest accurate places
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      // resp.coords.latitude
      // resp.coords.longitude
      console.log('Location ', resp);

      // Trigger searchSuggestionsForSport()
      // Will populate the suggestedPlaces$ variable
      this.clocationAvailable = true;
      this.searchSuggestionsForSport(this.sport);

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);

      // Set clocationAvailable to false which means that the user could not be geolocated (certainly because not granted)
      // This is used in view to display a message
      this.clocationAvailable = false;
    });
  }
```

My problem is, when I catch the geolocation error and that I set the clocationAvailable to false, my error message is well displayed but the spinner remains.

How could I handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use variable for visibility of loader.

```
<div *ngIf="loadingInProgress" #loading padding text-center></div>
```

controller

```
loadingInProgress: boolean = true; //loading in the begining

ionViewDidLoad() {
//stuff as before
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);

    this.loadingInProgress = false; //Changed visibility
});
```

}

### Edit

if you want to use *else* statement you need to use *ng-template*

```
<ng-template #loading>
    <div padding text-center>
        <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
        <p>
            Chargement...
        </p>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```